# How to create a token for an user using JWT AUTH in laravel 9

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpM2H.png)

I can create the user in the database but unlike the ones that exist that were added with seed it doesn't have an encrypted password and doesn't have a token, I need to generate the token to stop the user when he registers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwm2V.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use bcrypt for password hash and use random str for token before save data.

example:

```
User::create([
     'email' => $request->email,
     'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
     'token' => Str::random(80)
]);
```